# Showing two fragments side by side when a tab is clicked on the action bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

How can you show two fragments side by side?

I have tried `FragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer, myFragment)`,
where myFragment inflates a layout which contains two fragments that reference to my other fragment classes.

But this gives me an error saying `"myFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

check your import statements

Replace these statements

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

with these statements

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
```